# Can i use default TestNG thread framework for threading inside loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

I have 3 `@Test` methods in my class. In one of my `@Test` methods called `launchBuildAndGetStatus`, we have a for loop in which we perform some operation.

I want to implement multi-threading in the method `launchBuildAndGetStatus`, for example, leets say in this method my loop will run for 10 times.

Can I use any of the TestNG features to implement multi-threading in my code?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking for. Multi-threading is provided to you by Java and not by TestNG. TestNG just supports concurrency via some conventions. If you would like to implement multi-threading you should look at leveraging [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the particular test method with the multi-thread and multi-run follow the below example

In this example t3 method will execute with 2- thread and total time as 10.
so each thread will share and exeute the method

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Sample1 {

    @Test()
    public void t1(){
        System.out.println(" Test Case - t1" );
    }

    @Test()
    public void t2(){
        System.out.println(" Test Case - t2" );
    }

    @Test(threadPoolSize = 2 , invocationCount = 10)
    public void t3(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println(" Test Case - t3" );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried below code
 @Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 2,  timeOut = 100000)
 private void sample() throws InterruptedException{
  for (int i=1;i<5;i++){
   System.out.println("Test"+i);
  } 
 }
 
This gives output like
Test1
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test2
Test3
Test4

***

My requirement is something like below

Test1 (Thread 1)
Test2 (Thread 2)
Test3 (Thread 1)
Test4 (Thread 2)

In short, what i want is , my test method should run with multiple threads and if it has a loop , every thread should take incremented value of loop